# svn hangs when tunnelling through ssh

Tags: svn, ssh

I have a strange behavior when trying to use svn over ssh tunnel.
Environment: server running Ubuntu9.04, client running Debian Lenny
Symptoms: svn hangs both on client and server on some (but *not all*) long operations. E.g. *svn log* always works, committing some files may work, othes - don't.
What I tried:

- svn+ssh:// protocol
- creating a tunnel for 3690 port through ssh and using svn://
- creating a tunnel for 80 port through ssh and using http:// (with apache and mod_dav_svn on server)

All those with the same result. Updating svn to latest build doesn't change anything. It seems to be some ssh issue, but ssh itself works perfectly.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is SSH timing out while your long operation runs?